# Formatting strings in Asymptote

Tags: asymptote

I want to label a path with its calculated length.

This MWE nearly does what I want, but it prints the label as "1.4142135623731" which is far too much precision.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}

\begin{asy}
unitsize(10mm);
pair a = (0,0);
pair b = (1,1);
path p = (a--b);
draw(p);
label((string) arclength(p), p, SE);
\end{asy}

\end{document}
```

From the manual, it seems I can specify a `printf`-style formatting string like `%4.2f` somehow to get a label like "1.41", but I can't figure out from the manual how to put all the pieces together, or find an example to copy.

Comment: `label(string(arclength(p),3), p, SE);`. In the documentation http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/doc/Data-types.html#index-string-1

Comment: @O.G. that also "nearly works", but not if I want values like "1.23" and "987.65" to the same number of decimal places - I need to check the "number of digits" in each string after seeing what the calculated numbers are.

Comment: Do you mean example like `label(format("%4.2f",arclength(p)), p, SE);`?

Comment: And if you want to always have two decimal places, even if they are zeros, use a format of "%#4.2f".

Comment: @g.kov Yes that's the answer. I think I was getting tied in knots by thinking I needed an explicit cast - and/or not realizing the different between the `label()` function and the `Label` data type. (I've been using LaTeX for many years, but only just started with Asymptote.)

Comment: @James or even `%.2f`of course. The question wasn't about understanding`printf` formats, but about how to use them in Asymptote.

Comment: @alephzero: You can also try to look for the examples in the `example` and `base`
`Asymptote` installation folders.
For example, the search for `format(` 
gives the first match as
`iRhor=format("%.4gx", Rh);`
in
`asymptote-2.41/examples/tvgen.asy`.

Comment: @g.kov I didn't install asymptote - I'm using the version that came with TeXLive 2016. I don't seem to have those folders - and the "asymptote by example" PDF is literally in Chinese! The English documentation in TexLive seems to have been written by the same extraterrestrials who documented Metaplot ... :-(

Comment: @alephzero: OK, then, similarly, there is, for example 
a line `s += format("%.6f",colors[i],"C")+",";` 
from the one of the basic modules,
`texlive/2016/texmf-dist/asymptote/slide.asy`.
Anyways, you can always get the `Asymptote` source
from [`https://sourceforge.net/projects/asymptote/`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/asymptote)
or [`https://github.com/vectorgraphics/asymptote`](https://github.com/vectorgraphics/asymptote)
just as the source of examples, you don't 
have to compile/install it.