# How can I format strings by string type in Asymptote?

Tags: asymptote

I write an function that draws a vector with a label. I want to use a different font for the label. I have done below

```
texpreamble("\usepackage{amsmath}\usepackage{amsfonts}");
texpreamble("\renewcommand\vec[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}");

arrowbar vecArrow=ArcArrow(SimpleHead);

void drawV(pair begin, real leng, real angle=0, 
              Label label="", align align=N,
              arrowbar arrow=vecArrow, arrowbar bar=None,
              picture pic = currentpicture,
              pen p=currentpen, 
              margin margin=NoMargin, 
              marker marker=nomarker){
    path v;
    v=begin--(begin.x+leng, begin.y);
    rotate(angle, begin)*v;

    Label L="$\vec{...}$";       // <-- What can I do here?

    draw(pic=pic, L=L, align=align, v, p=p, arrow=arrow, bar=bar);
    dot(pic=pic, p=p, begin, filltype=dotfilltype);
}

drawV((0,0),5);
```

In my instance, I give a plain label (or strings) parameter, and the function wll change the final fiont, so that I don't have to write the font-changing code specially.

But I doesn't know how to format the `L` with the given parameter `label`.  Have there been any solutions?

Comment: Maybe something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386553/formatting-strings-in-asymptote#comment957988_386553

Comment: You only need to use built-in functions in Asymptote. If possible, don't complicate matters. :))

Comment: @user202729 Well, I tried the `format` function just now, but it seems that it only support   number data type to strings. In my instance, I want to format the result by a string type. Maybe I need to use the `insert` step by step.

Comment: @NguyenVanChi1998 Well, I just want to draw a lot of graphs with many similar characteristics. So defining several functions is an efficient way helping me work. If not needed, I will avoid this.

Comment: How did you try? If it's anything like C format you need `%s` instead of `%f` – read the documentation for the possible options, I guess.

Comment: Maybe `Label L = "$\vec{" + label + "}$";` ?

Comment: @user202729 I have tried `%s`, but it doesn't work. Whereas, if I try `%f` with a number, it works.

Comment: the `format` function is only defined with `int` or `real` arguments.  You can either concatenate strings with `+` or use `replace` to replace your own place holder with a string argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working, simplified version of your function.  Give me a comment if you have any questions or want me to show any additional functionality.

```
texpreamble("\usepackage{amsmath}\usepackage{amsfonts}");
texpreamble("\renewcommand\vec[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}");

unitsize(1cm);

void drawV(pair begin, real leng, real angle=0, string label="")
{
    path v = shift(begin)*rotate(angle)*((0,0)--(leng,0));

    string str = "$\vec{" + label + "}$";

    draw(Label(rotate(angle)*str), v, Arrow(SimpleHead));
    dot(begin, 3+black);
}

drawV((0,0), 5, 30, "test");
```

[image]